# Perl Script to Both Replace Extension Name and Trim White Space

Tags: perl

I am new to perl.

Currently, my task is to loop through all the .htm files in the folder and do two things:

1. Replace all the ".htm" extension to ".xml"
2. Replace all the white space in the file name to underscore.

In my perl script, I put in these two lines:

```
@pub=`ls $sourceDir | grep '\.htm' | grep -v Default |  head  -550`;
foreach (@pub) {

my $docName = $_;
chomp($docName);

    $docName =~ s/.htm$//g;
    $docName =~ s/ /_/g;
             ....}
```

$docName is the variable that holds the current full name of the file (including extension). Interestingly, those two $docName replacement statements, at any time, only the above one worked. For example, the example code here, will only replace the extension but leaves out the space, but if I comment out the first, then white space turns into underscore perfectly, but extensions remain ".htm".

Could experts help me? And could also suggest where I went wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the first place your regex `.htm$` will look for a pattern that has any character followed by htm at the end of the string, because the `.` means any character. If you want a literal period you need to use `\.`

Comment: And the `s/.htm$//g` will remove the `.htm` rather than replace it with `.xml`, and since you are looking for a single instance at the end of a the line, the `g` is probably uneeded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that's all

```
$docName =~ s/.htm$//g;
```

is doing?

You need to escape the `.` and add your replacement string. You also don't need `g` since right anchor guarantees it can only happen once.

```
$docName =~ s/\.htm$/\.xml/;
```

Other than that, you should be fine.

Comment: Actually if you had a string that was `.htm.htm.htm.htm.htm.htm.htm` the `g` would probably gobble them all up.

Comment: @Zeke: It worked. Actually I am doing an XSLT in Perl:system("java -Xms256m -Xmx512m -jar $saxonJar -o $tmpFile $inFile $xslFile $saxonParams")  . If there is space in $inFile, then the syntax is wrong, but normally we could get around that by putting a quotes around $inFile, do you know how to achieve that in my above Java statment?

Comment: @Zeke: No, `/\.htm$/` would only find the last one since it is anchored.

Comment: @Robert - you just need to put quotes around it in your `system()` - `Perl:system("java -Xms256m -Xmx512m -jar $saxonJar -o $tmpFile \"$inFile\" $xslFile $saxonParams")` (note you have to escape the quotes)

Comment: I suspect that @Zeke was reasoning that, after the final `.htm` is removed from the end of the string, there will still be a `.htm` at the end, so that one also gets removed, etc. The reason this won't happen is because, after performing a substitution, the regex engine does not backtrack to see whether the substitution created any new matches. If it did, then `s/a/aa/g` would cause an infinite loop any time it was run against a string containing the letter `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
my @pub = grep { ! /Default/ } glob( '*.htm' );

for my $pub ( @pub ){
  $pub =~ s{ \. htm \z }{}msx;
  $pub =~ s{ \s+ }{_}gmsx;
  print "$pub\n";
}
```

See:

```
perldoc -f glob
perldoc -f grep
perldoc perlretut
perldoc perlre
```